# Hive Expression not in GROUP BY key 'pat_dtl_start_dt' (state=42000,code=10025)

Tags: sql, group-by, hiveql

SQL Code:

```
CREATE TABLE dev.new STORED AS orc tblproperties("orc.compress" = "SNAPPY") AS
SELECT pat_dtl_start_dt, individual_id, bdy_lctn_cd, prcdr_cd, trtmnt_cd, SUM(allw_amt)
FROM dev.old
GROUP BY pat_dtl_start_dt, individual_id, bdy_lctn_cd, prcdr_cd, trtmnt_cd;
```

Error Message:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 2:7 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'pat_dtl_start_dt' (state=42000,code=10025)

I think I already include all selected columns in the group by key. Don't know why this still happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GROUP BY` looks correct . . . enough.  I don't see why it is causing that error.

However, you probably don't want `allw_amt` in it.  I am guessing that this does what you want:

```
SELECT pat_dtl_start_dt, individual_id, bdy_lctn_cd, prcdr_cd, trtmnt_cd,
       SUM(allw_amt)
FROM dev.old
GROUP BY pat_dtl_start_dt, individual_id, bdy_lctn_cd, prcdr_cd, trtmnt_cd;
```